# Dynamics CRM Web API - Are Actions supported via the $batch endpoint?

Tags: json, odata, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-webapi

I have successfully used the `$batch` endpoint of the Dynamics 365 Web API to create many appointments.

```
https://myorg.com/api/data/v8.2/$batch
```

The request body looks something like this:

```
--batch_AAA123
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=changeset_BBB456

--changeset_BBB456
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-ID: 1

POST https://myorg.com/api/data/v8.2/appointments HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;type=entry

{ ... JSON for appointment ... }

--changeset_BBB456
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-ID: 2

POST https://myorg.com/api/data/v8.2/appointments HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;type=entry

{ ... JSON for appointment ... }

--changeset_BBB456--

--batch_AAA123--
```

Instead of using the `appointments` endpoint I want to use the `Book` action.

```
https://myorg.com/api/data/v8.2/Book
```

I can do this successfully individually:

```
{
  "Target": {
    "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.appointment",
    "subject": "Created using Book action",
    "scheduledstart" : "2018-01-18T09:00:00Z",
    "scheduledend": "2018-01-18T10:00:00Z",
    "statecode" : 3,
    "statuscode" : 5,
    "ownerid@odata.bind":"/systemusers(f6c98954-66d3-e711-80eb-3863bb342b28)",
    "appointment_activity_parties" : [
    {
      "partyid_systemuser@odata.bind" : "/systemusers(f6c98954-66d3-e711-80eb-3863bb342b28)",
      "participationtypemask" : 7
    }
    ],
    "regardingobjectid_account@odata.bind": "/accounts(8df157f6-fcf5-e711-80ef-3863bb34ecf0)"
  }
}
```

Now I want to use the `Book` action via `$batch` but I get the error:

> VerifyCommitted - Transaction has not been committed

There is no further detail apart from a long stack trace.

I am confident that if carried out individually the booking would succeed (there are no scheduling conflicts etc.)

Am I doing something wrong or does the Web API simply not support actions in batch?

Comment: Can you send action request out of the change set or in a different change set? If I am right, all of the request within same change set are executed within a single SQL transaction, and probably that should have raised the error you are seeing.

Comment: I've run into this same problem.  Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: @JustinGreene Unfortunately not. Even a batch containing only one entry failed like this. When booked separately it succeeded. I ran out of time to research further and just booked everything individually instead. Sorry!